# Why was this keyword deemed important?

Tags: silent-sea

In [*The Silent Sea*](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt11570202/), Doctor Song Ji-an travels to Balhae Station located on the moon. Related to this, she remembers a seemingly important note from her late sister asking her to "find Luna".

For some reason, she is convinced that "Luna" must be something within Balhae Station.

**Is there any indication to this?**

We are talking about a moon base, and "Luna" is what the moon as a whole is sometimes called. How did Song Ji-an figure out "Luna" is supposed to be something of importance within Balhae Station, rather than assuming that "find Luna" just means "find the moon", as some kind of general request to come to said moon base? Did I miss anything that was said to this end during the show?